# Resources To Learn AppleScript For Mac System 7.5.5

Tags: resources, applescript

I'm back here is SO, i was a time out because i get sad with some persons that dislike me only because i was noob in C/C++ and now i'm very nice on it and my OS is started!.

But the thing is that now i'm emulating **Mac System 7.5.5 68k**, just for fun and for development too(AppleScript), but i was searching in the internet about this and i didn't find anything much intersthing, then i get here to know where i can find some good resources for this old version of AppleScript.

Thanks!

Comment: The Apple language reference in English from that era was 'AppleScript Language Guide: English Dialect' which Apple also made available in PDF form. I don't know if Apple still hosts it, but you can find archived copies of it elsewhere e.g. http://mirror.macintosharchive.org/ftp.macsoft/Mac%20OS%20Soft/Apple%20Support%20Documents/001%20-%20Service%20Manuals/Misc%20Devices/AppleScriptLanguageGuide.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Danny Goodman's [AppleScript Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0966551419) was always the best AppleScript reference since the OS 7 days. For good or ill, the AppleScript language has changed little in over fifteen years so a late edition will still be useful.

If you must have a reference for the original OS 7 version you have to look for an out-of-print edition, this can be done from Amazon or [Abe Books](http://www.abebooks.com/), among others.